# Error: Cannot find module '‘global-agent/bootstrap’'

Tags: node.js, electron, theia

I am trying to build theia project using yarn but am facing 2 issues.

I cloned Theia repo but when building using yarn

```
kriouana@TUN MINGW64 ~/Desktop/theia (master)
$ yarn
```

I got this error related to some file called INSTALL.JS

```
error C:\Users\kriouana\Desktop\theia\node_modules\electron: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: node install.js
Arguments:
Directory: C:\Users\kriouana\Desktop\theia\node_modules\electron
Output:
RequestError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND github.com
```

So after searching about this issue I found this

```
yarn global add global-agent
cd <clone_dir>/theia/node_modules/electron
node -r ‘global-agent/bootstrap’ install.js
```

but when executing the last line this came up

```
$ node -r ‘global-agent/bootstrap’ install.js
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:988
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '‘global-agent/bootstrap’'
Require stack:
- internal/preload
```

its something related to node and install.js and global-agent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have already found the solution just I wrote the wrong quote `‘ ’` when I should use `' '`,

```
node -r 'global-agent/bootstrap' install.js
```